# Why is the value of my variable not being updated inside a function?

Tags: javascript

I am developing a web app that displays a strobe light effect on the screen according to a certain tempo (BPM) set by the user. I want the parameters that control the strobe to be changable when the actual function that controls the strobe is running, not only when it's off. For that, I am using event listeners:

```
// manual bpm variable definition and event listener
var manualBPM = 0;
var manualBPM_text = document.getElementById("manual-value");
manualBPM_text.addEventListener("change", function() {
  manualBPM = manualBPM_text.value;
}, false);

// strobe duration variable definition and event listener
var duration = 100;
var slider = document.getElementById("MM-duration-slider");
slider.addEventListener("input", function() {
  duration = slider.value;
}, false);

var strobeActive = false;

/* ----- Manual mode ON button ----- */
function MM_turnOn() {
  //var manualBPM = document.getElementById("manual-value").value;

  if (!manualBPM && BPMvalueSource == "manual") {
    window.alert("Please insert a BPM value or use the tempo tapper.");
  } else if (!tapBPM && BPMvalueSource == "tap") {
    window.alert("Please use the tempo tapper or insert a BPM value.");
  } else {
    var MM_onBtn = document.getElementById("MM-on");
    var MM_offBtn = document.getElementById("MM-off");
    var resetTapperBtn_a = document.getElementById("reset-tapbpm-a");
    var resetTapperBtn_h = document.getElementById("reset-tapbpm-h");

    // disable on button (selected) and reset tapper bpm and enable off button
    MM_onBtn.setAttribute("disabled", "true");
    MM_offBtn.removeAttribute("disabled");
    resetTapperBtn_a.setAttribute("disabled", "true");
    resetTapperBtn_a.removeAttribute("onclick");

    // styling
    MM_onBtn.classList.remove("text-gray-700");
    MM_onBtn.classList.remove("hover:scale-1125");
    MM_onBtn.classList.add("text-themeOrange");

    MM_offBtn.classList.add("text-gray-700");
    MM_offBtn.classList.add("hover:scale-1125");
    MM_offBtn.classList.remove("text-themeOrange");

    resetTapperBtn_h.classList.remove("cursor-pointer");
    resetTapperBtn_h.classList.remove("hover:text-themeOrange");

    strobeActive = true;

    const body = document.querySelector("body");
    var interval = 0;
    var ranTimes = 0;

    if (BPMvalueSource == "manual") {
      interval = (60 / manualBPM) * 1000; //manualBPM not updating

      // repeat once the interval expires
      window.strobeTimeout = setInterval(function() {
        // trigger strobe
        body.classList.remove("bg-black");
        body.classList.add("bg-white");

        // kill strobe once the strobe duration expires
        setTimeout(function() {
          body.classList.remove("bg-white");
          body.classList.add("bg-black");
        }, duration);

        ranTimes++;
        console.log("BPM: " + manualBPM + " (source: " + BPMvalueSource + ") | Strobe duration: " + duration + "ms | " + "Times ran: " + ranTimes);
      }, interval);
    } else if (BPMvalueSource == "tap") {
      interval = (60 / tapBPM) * 1000; //tapBPM not updating

      // repeat once the interval expires
      window.strobeTimeout = setInterval(function() {
        // trigger strobe
        body.classList.remove("bg-black");
        body.classList.add("bg-white");

        // kill strobe once the strobe duration expires
        setTimeout(function() {
          body.classList.remove("bg-white");
          body.classList.add("bg-black");
        }, duration);

        ranTimes++;
        console.log("BPM: " + tapBPM + " (source: " + BPMvalueSource + ") | Strobe duration: " + duration + "ms | " + "Times ran: " + ranTimes);
      }, interval);
    }
  }
}

function killStrobe() {
  strobeActive = false;
  // function to turn off the strobe cycle
  clearInterval(strobeTimeout);
}
```

The problem that I am having is related to the value of "manualBPM" and "tapBPM" not being updated inside of the function that controls the strobe. On the console, shown the variable value is correct, but as I previously mentioned, the value within the function is not. My confusion comes from the fact that the "duration" variable (value comes from a range input) is in fact being updated, while the others are not.

I have a Github repo of the entire project, which might help finding the solution, because the code I pasted onto the question is dependant of other files. Plus it might help with visualizing or understanding the context of my problem. Feel free to check it out: https://github.com/SubZone-1/Synchroma

The app's link: https://subzone-1.github.io/Synchroma/ (Please be aware that the auto mode is not functional, as I haven't started to work on it yet.)

I have been searching for an appropriate solution, however to no avail. The fact that the console displays the variable's correct value rules out almost all of the possible solutions I have found so far, indicating that the way the variable is being assigned is likely not the issue.

Thank you for taking the time to read my question :)

Comment: The variable `tapBPM` does not seem to be defined anywhere. Same with `BPMValueSource`.

Comment: Also things like `MM_offBtn.classList.add("hover:scale-1125");` are not going to work if what you're trying to do is update the "hover" CSS rules.

Comment: I don't see where you change the value of manualBPM you change the value of interval, not manualBPM

Comment: @Pointy `tapBPM` and `BPMValueSource` are defined on a separate JS file. Regarding your other comment, it does work because I am using Tailwind CSS, which works by styling elements using classes.

Comment: @Supersub the `manualBPM` variable is being assigned an `<input>` value from the HTML file of the page on the very first event listener.

Comment: I tried your site and it seemed to work for me. I changed the frequency, turned the strobe off and on, and it used the new frequency.

Comment: If you expect the frequency to change without turning it off and on, you need to call `killStrobe()` and `mm_turnOn()` in the `change` event listener.

Comment: @Barmar I aprecciate your feedback, and I am aware that the frequency does change whenever you turn the strobe off and on. The point of the question is to make the frequency change while the strobe is on without having to turn it off and on again. Calling the strobe functions  in the `change` listener also doesn't work because it renders the ON and OFF buttons useless.

Comment: Then instead of using `setInterval()`, use `setTimeout()`. The function can call `setTimeout()` at the end to schedule the next blip, and use the current value of `manualBMP` to calculate the delay.